# Modifying code to fix Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here's my code:

```
SELECT
LEFT(o.JobNo,5) AS 'Order Number',
CAST(SUBSTRING(o.PartNo,CHARINDEX('.',o.PartNo)+1, 
CHARINDEX('.',o.PartNo,CHARINDEX('.',o.PartNo)+1) -
CHARINDEX('.',o.PartNo)-1) AS INT) AS 'ItemNo',
o.PartNo,
o.JobNo,
CAST(od.PartDesc AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS 'Description',
o.WorkCntr,
FORMAT(o.TotEstHrs*60, 'N3') AS 'Estimated Minutes',
FORMAT(COALESCE(SUM(t.ManHrs*60), 0),'N3') AS 'Actual Minutes',
FORMAT(COALESCE(SUM(t.ManHrs*60)/NULLIF((o.TotEstHrs*60), 0), 0), 'P') AS 
'Actual to V6'
FROM OrderRouting o
JOIN WorkCntr w ON 
o.WorkCntr = w.ShortName
LEFT JOIN TimeTicketDet t ON 
o.JobNo = t.JobNo
AND w.WorkCntr = t.WorkCntr
LEFT JOIN OrderDet od ON
o.JobNo = od.JobNo
WHERE
od.OrderNo IN ('20040')
AND w.ShortName IN ('Cutting', 'Framing', 'Assembly', 'Grinding', 
'Painting', 'Glazing', 'Locknprep', 'Packaging')
GROUP BY LEFT(o.JobNo,5), CAST(SUBSTRING(o.PartNo,CHARINDEX('.',o.PartNo)+1, 
CHARINDEX('.',o.PartNo,CHARINDEX('.',o.PartNo)+1) -
CHARINDEX('.',o.PartNo)-1) AS INT), o.PartNo, o.JobNo, CAST(od.PartDesc AS 
NVARCHAR(MAX)), o.WorkCntr, o.TotEstHrs
ORDER BY LEFT(o.JobNo,5), CAST(SUBSTRING(o.PartNo,CHARINDEX('.',o.PartNo)+1, 
CHARINDEX('.',o.PartNo,CHARINDEX('.',o.PartNo)+1) -
CHARINDEX('.',o.PartNo)-1) AS INT);
```

I'm getting the error because a small % of my part numbers don't have a second period.  Most of my part numbers are like this:

20040.1.1

20040.1.1.1

20040.1.1.2

20040.10.1

20040.10.1.1

20040.10.2

But some can be like this, which is why I'm getting the error:

20040.11

20040.12

20040.13

In those instances, I would simply need to extract the digits after the period (11, 12, 13).  How can I modify my code to make it work for both type of part numbers?  Using SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple patch for your code is to add '.' to the end of your `PartNo` like so:

```
select 
  ItemNo = cast(substring(
        o.PartNo
      , charindex('.',o.PartNo)+1
      , charindex('.',o.PartNo+'.',charindex('.',o.PartNo)+1) -
        charindex('.',o.PartNo)-1
        ) 
      as int)
```

Also, you shouldn't use string literals for aliases. Get rid of those single quotes, and if you are using an irregular identifier enclose it in square brackets.

---

```
declare @PartNo varchar(32) = '20040.13'

select 
  ItemNo = cast(substring(
        @PartNo
      , charindex('.',@PartNo)+1
      , charindex('.',@PartNo+'.',charindex('.',@PartNo)+1) -
        charindex('.',@PartNo)-1
        ) 
      as int)
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/WSEP30461

returns:

```
+--------+
| ItemNo |
+--------+
|     13 |
+--------+
```

Comment: That was a very simple patch indeed, works great.  Regarding the aliases, is that just a more proper code writing practice?

Comment: @user1452574 Sorry for the delay. Using string literals for column aliases has been deprecated for some time now and is not supported on some sql server platforms (e.g. Azure). Other reasons are explained here: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using AS instead of = for column aliases - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases)

Answer (score 1):

I think @SqlZim answer seems better and simpler. But, in case you looking for an alternative you can simply test if the string has multiple "." and based on the number of "." you can extract the correct string.

Here is a sample based on your sample set:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Parts') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Parts
CREATE TABLE #Parts
(
    PartNo NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO #Parts
VALUES('20040.1.9')
,('20040.1.8.1')
,('20040.1.7.2')
,('20040.10.3')
,('20040.10.99.1')
,('20040.10.98')
,('20040.11')
,('20040.12')
,('20040.13')

SELECT
CAST(
        CASE 
        WHEN LEN(o.PartNo) - LEN(REPLACE(o.PartNo, '.', '')) >= 2 THEN
            SUBSTRING(
                         o.PartNo
                        ,CHARINDEX('.', o.PartNo) + 1
                        ,CHARINDEX('.', o.PartNo, CHARINDEX('.',o.PartNo) + 1) - CHARINDEX('.',o.PartNo) - 1
                     )
        ELSE
            SUBSTRING(o.PartNo, CHARINDEX('.', o.PartNo) + 1, (LEN(o.PartNo) - (CHARINDEX('.', o.PartNo)) ))
        END  
        AS NVARCHAR(100)
     ) AS 'ItemNo'
     ,o.PartNo
FROM #Parts o
```

Comment: I was thinking I was going to have to do something like this, but yea, his answer is pretty simple and it works.  Although I feel your answer might be useful in other similar scenarios, so thanks for submitting it

Answer (score 1):

**ParseName()** seems like a potential fit here

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values 
('20040.1.1'),
('20040.1.1.1'),
('20040.1.1.2'),
('20040.10.1'),
('20040.10.1.1'),
('20040.10.2'),
('20040.11'),
('20040.12'),
('20040.13')

Select * 
      ,Pos1 = reverse(parsename(reverse(SomeCol),1))
      ,Pos2 = reverse(parsename(reverse(SomeCol),2))
      ,Pos3 = reverse(parsename(reverse(SomeCol),3))
      ,Pos4 = reverse(parsename(reverse(SomeCol),4))
 From  @YourTable
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: This is actually pretty genius, thank you.  Question though, if my part number had 5 parts, would it still work or would ParseName crash?

Comment: @user1452574 Correct only 4 parts